# Is there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f''$ is continuous and these properties $P(f)$ hold?

Tags: calculus, functions

By $]a, b[$ we mean an open interval.

Is there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1) $f''$ is continuous;

2) $f'' > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$;

3) $f'(0) = 1;$

4) $f \leq 100$ on $]0, \infty[$?

Is there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 1), 2), 3) hold for $f$ with 4) replaced by 4') $f \leq 100$ on $]\infty, 0[$?

My problem is I do not see a useful property to link 1), 2), 3) to 4) and 4').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f'' > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ means that $f'$ is increasing, so that for $x > 0$ we have $f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^x f'(t)dt \geq f(0) + x f'(0) = f(0) + x$. Can property ($4$) hold?

For property ($4'$), it should be fairly easy for you to construct an example (think exponential).

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry that I mistakenly specified conditions 4) and 4'). Please refer to the present revision.